# Parser Json PHP

Tags: php, json

```
    [{"data":{"attr":{"href":"http://www.google.com/","title":"http://www.google.com/"},"title":"Google"},"attr":{},"metadata":{}},
    {"data":{"attr":{"href":"http://www.yandex.com/","title":"http://www.yandex.com/"},"title":"Яндекс"},"attr":{"class":""},"metadata":{}}]
```

Help get the links from Json. Get the links of a given form of Json

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" title="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.yandex.com/" title="http://www.yandex.com/">Яндекс</a>
```

Comment: get the links of a given form of Json

Comment: either google, or [RTFM](http://www.php.net/json_decode) -> `$parsed[0]['data']['attr']['href']`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanx for [0]['data']['attr']['href']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seemed to be the correct answer, and I've just set a bounty I could do with the rep of an accepted answer:

either google, or [RTM](http://www.php.net/json_decode) -> `$parsed[0]['data']['attr']['href']`

Comment: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"
such errors and I was getting. therefore think it is wrong to do. but again the same. Why?

Comment: Read the docs: if you use `json_decode($theString);` you'll get objects, if you use `json_decode($theString,true);` you'll get arrays. In case of objects, mostly (`ArrayAccess` aside), you'll access the data like so: `$parsed[0]->data->attr->href`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking to get the links from the json in PHP:

```
$links = json_decode($putYourJSONinsideThisVariable, true);

echo $links[0]['data']['attr']['href'];
```